# jQuery - jScrollPane doesn't show the scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jscrollpane

i'm trying to set up the jScrollpane plugin for jquery. I followed exactly the how to @ http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#usage but unfortunately the scroll bars don't show up. If I remove the plugin, standard system scrollbars are shown (as expected).

Here is the code. In the head tag of my page I have:

```
<!-- my CSSs -->
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="/artwriter/resources/styles/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- my scripts -->
<script src="/artwriter/resources/js/artwriter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/artwriter/resources/js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/artwriter/resources/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

where '.scroll-pane' is the class of my div tag.

I have tried with webkit web developer tools and every link looks correct, but scrollbar don't show up.
I'm using the latest version of the plugin (I just downloaded it from the plugin site).
Any idea?

Thanks,
Stefano

Comment: Please provide a link to the site you have made. The likley thing is either a css conflict or javascript error.

Comment: Sorry but I can't. I'm still developing.

Comment: Richard I was able to put online a simple page that presents the same error http://87.2.181.169:8080/artwriter/
This is an awful page, but presents a div that should contain the scrollbars.

Comment: On that link you are calling the jScrollPane function before you load the plugin, maybe is that?

Comment: I call the jScrollPane() function only on DOM loaded.
I've added an alert to check this. Isn't this the usage of jQuery $(function(){...})?

Comment: Inspecting the DOM I found that a style is actually added to my DIV node: style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; width: 300px;"
Maybe I'm missing some graphic resource not mentioned in the how to?

Comment: Always insepcting the DOM I found that inside my DIV two more divs have been created (with the second nested in the first).
The outer has the class 'jspContainer', the inner has the class 'jspPane': they are rendered apparently below my div considering the height it should have to contain all the "Loerm ipsum....".

Comment: stefano Simplest way to get around it: I take it you've downloaded the zip. Take the basic html demo or what ever example you need, move the required linked files to your dir, add your script links & css to the page bit by bit refreshing as you add, if it breaks you will know exactly what is conflicting.

Comment: thx julien I've done as you suggested and
D'OH! the silliest thing! you *must* put your content inside a <p>...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was definitely trivial in my case: simply, the content must be placed inside a < p > or a < div > i.e.:

```
<div class="scrollable">
MY CONTENT BLA BLA BLA
</div>
```

wont' work, you have to write

```
<div class="scrollable">
<p>MY CONTENT BLA BLA BLA</p>
</div>
```

Hope this will help,

Stefano

Answer (score -1):

If you had to add `<p>` to get the bars to be visible, then you may have a CSS conflict with your stylesheet and the scrollbar stylesheet...I don't have and never use `<p>` in my stylings and the bars are visible for me with no problem. I found a CSS error when I had issues with the bars not displaying properly...